# How to build inner join in Rails with conditions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, pgadmin

I've a model `StockUpdate` which keeps track of stocks for every product for a store. Table attributes are: `:product_id, :stock, :store_id`. I was trying to find out last entry for every product for a given store. According to that I build my query in PGAdmin which is given below and it's working fine. I'm new in Rails and I don't know how to represent it in Model. Please help.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    stock_updates a
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT product_id, MAX(id) max_id
        FROM    stock_updates where store_id = 9 and stock > 0
        GROUP BY product_id
    ) b ON a.product_id = b.product_id AND
            a.id = b.max_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is really simple and can be easily accomplished with 2 queries. Otherwise it becomes very complicated in a single query (it's still doable though):

```
store_ids = [0, 9]
latest_stock_update_ids = StockUpdate.
                          where(store_id: store_ids).
                          group(:product_id).
                          maximum(:id).
                          values
StockUpdate.where(id: latest_stock_update_ids)
```

Two queries, without any `joins` necessary. The same could be possible with a single query too. But like your original code, it would include subqueries.

**Something** like this should work:

```
StockUpdate.
where(store_id: store_ids).
where("stock_updates.id = (
    SELECT MAX(su.id) FROM stock_updates AS su WHERE (
      su.product_id = stock_updates.product_id
    )
  )
")
```

Or **perhaps**:

```
StockUpdate.where("id IN (
  SELECT MAX(su.id) FROM stock_updates AS su GROUP BY su.product_id
)")
```

And to answer your original question, you can manually specify a `joins` like so:

```
Model1.joins("INNER JOINS #{Model2.table_name} ON #{conditions}")
# That INNER JOINS can also be LEFT OUTER JOIN, etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

I does not clearly understand what you want to do, but I think you can do something like this:

```
class StockUpdate < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :a_good_name, -> { joins(:product).where('store_id = ? and stock > ?', 9, 0) }
end
```

You can all call `StoclUpdate.a_good_name.explain` to check the generated sql

Comment: Not working. It's generating query like `SELECT "stock_updates".* FROM "stock_updates" INNER JOIN "products" ON "products"."id" = "stock_updates"."product_id" WHERE "stock_updates"."store_id" = 9 AND (stock > 0)`

Comment: Using scopes for something like this is probably the best route. [More on Scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes)